# Command to view which version of NixOS my machine is running?

Tags: version, nixos

At https://nixos.org/ I can view the recent releases of NixOS.

Is there a command I can run to see which version is on my machine?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Nixos manual](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/):

```
nixos-version
```

Answer (score 7):

```bsh
$ nix-info -m
 - system: `"x86_64-linux"`
 - host os: `Linux 5.10.79, NixOS, 21.05.4116.46251a79f75 (Okapi)`
 - multi-user?: `yes`
 - sandbox: `yes`
 - version: `nix-env (Nix) 2.3.16`
 - channels(root): `"nixos-21.05.4116.46251a79f75"`
 - channels(roman): `""`
 - nixpkgs: `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos`
```

- `host os` shows what version system is on
- `channels(root)` shows what is the updated channel version
- `channels(roman)` shows that user roman is not on a different channel than host

[image]

Source https://dopp.sk/posts/NixOS_channels/